# Java - call void function that print my name

Tags: java, function

```
 public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    **how i call the function here** ?


    }//public
    public static void nameAndAge() {
        System.out.println("Name: Rubik Seviyants   Age: 27");

    }

}//main
```

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any research.  Please [edit] your question to include the research you have done and *precisely* where you are having difficulty.  If you can do this, I may retract my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.pervacio.adminportal.tradein.constants;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        nameAndAge();
    }//public
    public static void nameAndAge() {
        System.out.println("Name: Rubik Seviyants   Age: 27");
    }
}//main
```

Please read this for better understanding: [Java Methods | Tutorials Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If the function that has to be called is in the same class then just call the function like this:

```
function_name(parameters);
```

But if the function is in another class then you will have to create an object of the class and call:

> Class_name object_name=new Class_name(); object_name.function_name();

Answer (score 0):

**These are the ways to call the function :**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        nameAndAge();
        // or
        Main.nameAndAge();
        // or
        Main s=new Main();
        s.nameAndAge();
    } //public
    public static void nameAndAge() {
        System.out.println("Name: Rubik Seviyants   Age: 27");
    }
}
```